# Generic search/filter function with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a generic search/filter function that can filter an array of any object based on a set of keys. How would I achieve something similar to this thing I sketched out without specifying the keys to to look at in the filter expression?

```
filteredItems: any[];
lastSearch: string;

public filter(items: any[], searchText: string) {
    if (searchText.length < 1 || searchText.length < this.lastSearch.length) {
        this.filteredItems = items;
    }

    var terms = searchText.split(" ");

    searchTerms.forEach(term => {
        this.filteredItems = this.filteredItems.filter(p => p.firstName.startsWith(term) || p.lastName.startsWith(term) || p.placeOfWork.startsWith(term))
    })

    return this.filteredItems;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: @ChrisBarr Something like this: https://pastebin.com/p3F5ssb8. The search string should then only give me a result for person1.

Comment: Can you please provide a complete code example? You have a partial class in your question and you have sample data on an external URL.  I have to assemble all of this and then fill in the missing pieces just to see how your code works. Please make it *easy* for someone to help you, you will get much better and faster results

Answer (score 0):

I saw the pastebin link you posted. If I understand your requirements correctly then this should work.

```
filteredItems: any[];
lastSearch: string;

public filter(items: any[], searchText: string) {
  if (searchText.length < 1 || searchText.length < this.lastSearch.length) {
    this.filteredItems = items;
  }

  const terms = searchText.split(" ").map(term => term.toLowerCase());

  this.filteredItems = items.filter(item => {
    for (const term of terms) {
      const foundMatch = Object.values(item).some(value => {
        if (typeof value === "string") {
          return value.toLowerCase().startsWith(term);
        }
        return false;
      });

      if (!foundMatch) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  });

  return this.filteredItems;
}
```

I've used the filter function to filter each array item depending on if the keys are present.